# I really have no clue how to print an array from a recursion formula

Tags: java, recursion

trying to return an int array of a Fibonacci sequence using recursion. but I just dont know how to put it into an array

```
public int[] fibArray(int n){

int[] result = new int[n];
  if(n<=2){
    result[0] = 1;
    result[1] = 1;
}else{
 result[n] = fibArray[n-1] + fibArray[n-2];
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: What's happening with the code you've shared? It seems to be returning an array of ints. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Cant add fibArray[n-1] and fibArray[n-2]

Comment: You need to be more specific, what does "Can't add" mean? Are you seeing an exception, is the result wrong?

Comment: Running the program as is, the compilation error is that both "fibArray" cannot be resolved to a variable. And the "+" operator cannot be applied to arguments int [], int[]

Comment: You need to call the method `fibArray`, but you're using square brackets, treating it like it's an array. The result is an array, not the method.

Comment: Not sure why you are doing it this way, but if it's not just for school I recommend passing (n, new int[n]) into the method and just re-using that array, constructing a new array each time you recurs just to grab the last two values is beyond inefficient, I'd go so far as to say it's bad programming.  If it's for school--well who knows what teachers value more, he may have some bug about modifying passed-in values or something (Although even if that is the case, returning an ArrayList would be a good solution that wouldn't require re-creating it all the time).

Answer (score 2):

You're treating the method like an array. It *returns* an array, it isn't one.

```
public int[] fibArray(int n){

  int[] result = new int[n];
  if(n<=2){
    result[0] = 1;
    result[1] = 1;
  }else{
    int[] previous = fibArray(n-1); // note the parens, not braces
    result[n] = previous[n-1] + previous[n-2]; // may be subject to off by one error, I trust you can fix that
  }
  return result;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I been trying to figure it out but I'm not too good with the syntax with arrays. there error that display is that index 3 is out of bounds for length 3. but if previous[n-1] shouldn't that be below the index?

Comment: If n is 3, the previous array would be of length 2. Remember array indices start at 0. You may need to include one or two -1 values in the right places

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initiailze your array outside of your `fibArray` function.

```
int[] callingFunc(int size){
  int[] myFibArray = new int[size]
  myFibArray[0] = 1;
  myFibArray[1] = 2;
  myFibArray = fibArray(2, myFibArray)
}

public int[] fibArray(int n){ 

//Your fib function
return result;
```

}

The way you have it now, you're initialising a new array with every recursive call and setting the size to n which is just the number of recursive calls.